# Create multiple child record when master record is created

Tags: job

I am trying to create a very similar process.
I have a custom object Job (master ) and other custom object Steps (child ) . Both of these are children in a master detailed relationship.

In a Job Object there are two record type 1. Lamination and 2 frames. In lamination there are job allocation steps like Plywood cutting, Past, tempering etc. Frame also has same things.

I need a process to create a new Order (job) which will automatically create new multiple steps, not a single step. I want multiple steps like, when I select lamination or frame all relevant job allocation steps to be created.
I am trying to use process builders’ which is creating only one step but I want multiple relevant steps for each record type

Comment: Ok, what is your actual question?

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple actions and criteria in the process builder as you desire. If you want to create a dozen different records, you can, just keep adding more actions. Or, you could create a Flow and call the Flow from the Process Builder, which would allow you to create a large number of records using drag-and-drop programming interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple actions in process builder if the no of child record count is static, or call the @InvocableMethod method of class from process builder by passing the parameter whatever you want, then create the child records using code.

https://blog.webnersolutions.com/salesforce-call-apex-class-from-process-builder